# @Rollback in TestNG Integration Test but entry in DB committed

Tags: spring, testng, spring-transactions

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ServiceConfig.class,PersistenceConfiguration.class, MailConfig.class })
@Transactional
public class CreateStatsIT extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Test
@Rollback
@Transactional
public void insertUserIT() {

    User u = new User(1L, "Test");
    u = userRepository.save(s);


    List<User> us = userRepository.findAll();

    System.out.println(us.size());

   }

}
```

I would expect that the user would not be present in the database after the completion of the test but it is. The Spring Integration Tests documentation describes that the tests rollback automatically and also that `@Rollback` does not let the transaction be committed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please refer to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34428936). Quoting the solution here for ease of reference. Please replace `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` with `AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring + TestNG not transactionally rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34419775/spring-testng-not-transactionally-rollback)