# Spring's TestNG rollback transaction not working

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testng, dao

Following my [general question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51277657/how-unit-test-insert-record-in-spring-no-delete-method/51277993?noredirect=1#comment89534370_51277993) I have a specific issue using spring `jdbcTemplate` , I want to rollback specific test method after every execution of DAO method below.

Adding `@Transactional` and `@Rollback(true)` failed to rollback insert

Also getting connection before/after and rollback it doesn't effect

```
@Test
@Transactional
@Rollback(true)
public void testInsertUser() {
    Assert.assertEquals(userDAO.insertUser(new User(55616103, true, true, false)), true);
}
```

How should I rollback unit test using TestNG framework? most [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626502/rollback-transaction-after-test) use Junit's `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`

I failed auto wiring the `jdbcTemplate` using TestNG:

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

But succeeded using `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` with including Configuration class includes jdbcTemplate/DataStource

Do TestNG have option to execute using Spring context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to replace the `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` with `AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests`.

reference: [Spring + TestNG not transactionally rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34419775/spring-testng-not-transactionally-rollback)